# Copy One Excel Sheet To Second Sheet By Sheet Index

Tags: excel, vba, copy

1. I want to copy from one Excel sheet to another in the same workbook using reference to the active sheet, not sheet name.
2. I want to refer to the destination range by a variable.

I have not found any examples of this.

1. I have tried setting

`currentSheet = ActiveSheet.Name,`

in the line

`Worksheets(currentSheet).Range("A1").Copy Worksheets("Report").Range("A1")` with `"currentSheet"` and `currentSheet`.

2. I have the following to find the next empty row

```
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
printRow = LastRow + 2
```

Likewise, I have tried setting  `.Range("A1")` to `.Range("PrintRow")` and  `.Range(PrintRow)`.

```
Sub CopyAndPrintToReport()
    'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
     Dim LastRow As Long
     Dim printRow As Long
     Dim currentSheet As String
     currentSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

     Worksheets("Report").Activate
     With ActiveSheet
         LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     End With

     printRow = LastRow + 2    

     Worksheets(currentSheet).Range("A1").Copy_ 
         Worksheets("Report").Range(printRow)

End Sub
```

I need to refer to the active sheet by `currentSheet = ActiveSheet.Name` and the destination range by `printRow`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a variable, you do not need to use the double quotes to refer to it (it won't work).

Also while you can store and use the name of the sheet in a variable, is generally better to declare the sheet itself as a variable and use that (or the very least, in this case for sure).

```vb
Sub CopyAndPrintToReport()    
     Dim LastRow As Long
     Dim printRow As Range
     Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
     Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet

     With Worksheets("Report")
         LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
         Set printRow = .Range(.Cells(LastRow + 2, "A"), .Cells(LastRow + 2, "A"))
         'Set printRow = .Cells(LastRow + 2, "A")
         'Set printRow = .Range("A" & LastRow + 2)
     End With

     currentSheet.Range("A1").Copy printRow
End Sub
```

Might worth renaming the variables into something like `sourceSheet` instead of `currentSheet`, but that comes with time.

I've set `printRow` to my way of selecting a range (bigger than just one cell), but see in the comments alternatives of doing the same thing, for a single cell.

Please let me know if i can assist further.